# How can I get a distinct count of values within a directory full of csv's

Tags: linux, grep

I have a directory full of csv's that have dates in them, but I want to count all unique timestamps associated with a record across all files, but the catcher is that these records can repeat across files, hence the issue. For example I have file_1 that has two columns an id and timestamp and I want to count all unique records for each month.

I have used this command `grep -E "2022-11-*" 2022-10* | wc -l` to search all October files to see dates in November, but I'm getting more than I expect because these records can be duplicated. Is there a way to do this. Here is some sample data that may be helpful.

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-04 16:02:02.000 |
| 2 | 2022-10-04 13:02:02.000 |

and then in the next file

| id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-04 16:02:02.000 |
| 3 | 2022-10-04 1:02:02.000 |

So based on these two files I would return a unique set of 3 instead of 4.

To add to this question, I created two test files on my computer to test some of the answers. And I got this

```
grep -E "2022-11-*" 2022-* | sort |
uniq -c
   1 2022-11-01.csv:1, 2022-11-17 21:09:56.000
   1 2022-11-01.csv:2, 2022-11-17 03:09:56.000
   1 2022-11-01.csv:3, 2022-11-09 01:10:54.000
   1 2022-11-02.csv:1, 2022-11-17 21:09:56.000
   1 2022-11-02.csv:2, 2022-11-17 03:09:56.000
   1 2022-11-02.csv:3, 2022-11-09 01:10:54.000
```

As you can see there are two files, but 3 of these records are duplicated across each file, so I should just get 3 as a response. So I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: thank you @JNevill I was trying to make those tables formatted correctly and I was struggling to do so.

Comment: The table markdown is a newer feature (the last year or two) and it's buggy in that shows correctly in the preview, but garbles when you submit the post. You have to have a blank line between text and the table markdown to make it work on submission. It's a silly bug.

Comment: Your command searches October files for dates in November, not vice-versa as you write.

Comment: Try `| sort | uniq -c`  or `| sort -u | wc -l` instead of `| wc -l`. The first one will give you the count for each line, the second one will eliminate duplicates before going to wc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a `sort -u` to your pipe.

```
grep -hE "2022-11-*" 2022-10* | sort -u | wc -l
```

Comment: I'm getting the same results, It doesn't seem like I'm capturing the overlap between the two directories.. maybe I am I guess I would have to verify to make sure these are the correct results.

Comment: `grep -E "2022-11-*" 2022-* | sort -u | wc -l` is what I'm using cause of the overlap in the directories and getting more than I expected, but maybe it's still right I'll have to check.

Comment: *".... the overlap between the two directories"* ?? You mean overlap between files or the "code" in your question needs updating. Good luck.

Comment: @Alex I can only go by your sample data, and on that it works.

Comment: sorry I just updated the question with more clarifying data. So I have two files, with data that is repeated across files in the same directory. I want to get a unique count of these records. So for this data I would expect a count of 3 not 6.

Comment: @Alex tell grep to suppress the output of the filename.  `grep -h`

Comment: ah gosh, thank you, I'm a noob as you can tell with Linux. Thanks so much!

Comment: @Alex no worries - we live and learn. ;)